# passing information ( HTML code ) to other ASP.NET (C#) website

Tags: c#, html

My problem is this:

I want to send HTML code to another website. Is there a special way for this to be sent? So that the other website knows what to do with it? (This is a friend of mine, who wanted to have my info on his website) The website expects it, so it can be handled from there.

I use C# .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass information securely then you really should be using SSL.
Another alternative would be to create a webservice that you friend can call to access the information using a variety of security techniques such as encryption and user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Erm,

if the other website just does a request of http://www.yoursite/somehtml.aspx he will get the html he needs to have.

Comment: But if my site doesnt have SSL, will this option work? It's secure information actually, so it needs to be safe.